# Get Cookie in Cookie format and pass it to a CookieStore?

Tags: java, android

I have a webview, which I have successfully (I think?) managed to get the cookies out of, however I then need to place these cookies into a CookieStore so I can add them to a HttpGet request.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Combine the second part of the second option of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690637/android-http-login-questions/5692496#5692496) with the cookie values you already have. The work left to do is to determine (and eventually parse) the cookie values and insert them into your `HttpURLConnection` object, and then make a request towards a web server.

If you are not sure whether you have grabbed the right cookies, you can check via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com/) and see if they correspond in a similar manner.

Or, check out the [Sessions with Cookies](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) part from the Android developers website.